# Unable to get the list of usernames from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am able to get the data of the push keys (posts data) but not able to  get the data from the users in which there is unique user id for every user.

I just wants to know how to get the list of usernames from the users section in the Firebase (Realtime Database) (Google).

Comment: We generally ask to see the code that you're stuck on - would you edit it into the question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Access All Inner Childerns Data Without knowing Upper Key Using This

```
 firebase.child("key").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot innerDataSanpShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              //DataSnapshot of inner Childerns
              String username = innerDataSnapShot.child("username").getValue().toString();
             } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```